# Is there any way to pause all eventListerners?

Tags: javascript, events, click, dom-events, onclicklistener

Is there any way to pause all the "click" event Listeners so that the new click event listener that I add will alone work ? I need to resume all the pre-existing event listeners later.

Thank You

Edit:
I added used stopPropogation() method add the end of new click event listener. And to resume all the pre-existing event listener I just deleted the new click listener. It worked perfectly !

Thanks for the support !

Comment: Is this specific to any element or all elements?

Comment: All elements. I however solved this one. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

You could route all your listeners through a central function that qualified if they should continue or not.

```js
let elems = document.querySelectorAll(".thing");

elems.forEach(el => el.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  if (okForMeToRun(e)) {
    console.log('I am allowed')
  } else {
    console.log('I am not allowed');
  }
}));

function okForMeToRun(e) {
  // in case we need to examine the event that wants to fire...
  console.log(e.target.innerText + ' wants to fire ')
  if (e.target.classList.contains('goodtogo')) return true;

  return false;
}
```

```html
<button class='thing goodtogo'>Test me </button> <button class='thing'>Then test me </button>
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for answer. However, I used the stopPropogation method. I found that more useful to my scenario. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation